Newly created React component doesn't show correct information
I have a father component containing a function that adds a new object to a useState objectList. This list is iterated over to show a list of child components that contain the information stored in the useState objects. Here's my father component.
const FatherComponent = (data) => {

    const [objectList, setObjects] = useState(data.objects)

    const addObject = useCallback(prevObjects => {

        setObjects([new Object(data.id, "", ""), ...objectList])

        data.id += 1
    }, [data])

    useEffect(() => {
        data.objects = objectList
        console.log(objectList)
    }, [objectList, data])

    return(
        {objectList.map((object) => (
                    <ChildComponent
                        object={object}
                        objectList={objectList}
                        setObjects={setObjects}
                    />
                ))}
    );
}

class Object {
    constructor(
        id,
        name,
        description) {
         this._id = id
         this._name = name
         this._description = description
     }

    //getters and setters

The console.log in the useEffect hook returns the correct values whenever a test is added. Suppose I add a test, I write 'name' in the name textbox and then I add another text, the console.log will print the following:
0: Object { _id: 1, _name: "", _description: ""}
​
1: Object { _id: 0, _name: "name", _description: ""}

All should be easy from now on but it isn't. the newly created component takes the place of the old one and pushes it down. The new component has the same fields of the old component but it shouldn't as the console.log above shows. Here is the code of the child component:
const ChildComponent = (object, objectList, setObjects) => {
    
    //keep an eye on this, I'll talk about it shortly
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(object)
    }, [])

    const [name, setName] = useState(object.name)

    const handleName = (event) => {
        setName(event.target.value)
    }

    const [description, setDescription] = useState(object.description)

    const handleDescription = (event) => {
        setDescription(event.target.value)
    }

        useEffect(() => {
            let newObjectList = [...objectList]
            let newObject = new Object(object.id, name, objective)
            let index = newObjectList.findIndex(objectComp => objectComp.id === test.id)

            newObjectList[index] = newObject

            setObjects(newObjectList)
    }, [name, description])

    return (
        <div>
            <input type='text' placeholder='Object name' className='nameTextBox'
                    value={name}
                    onChange={handleName}>
            </input>
            <textarea type='text' className='objectTextBox'
                value={description}
                onChange={handleDescription}>
            </textarea>
        </div>

    );
}


You should give your components a key prop when you're mapping them.

what is "testComponents" in your fatherComponent useEffect?  and what is "prevTests" in your addObject function?
i'm confused by what the fatherComponent useEffect is trying to accomplish.  it should not be trying to change the incoming property passed in from its parent.  have you console.logged the objectList itself?

@sparkJ oh my mistake, just a typo, corrected it

@NickParsons Perfect!, that was the problem!

@NickParsons If you want you can post that as an answer
